# Garbage Collection and Citrix Server

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

If I have an C# winforms application that runs on a Citrix server, will i improve the performance of the Garbage Collector by telling the CLR to load the Server GC?

Comment: You can perform measurements and compare the two. It is dependent on a lot of factors that you know more about than us. Have you noticed any issue that warrants looking into this in the first place?

Comment: no i have just been watching the memory usage of the application in task manager and notice that the memory is not always decreasing as forms are being closed and memory is no long needed. I am assuming this is because the server has plenty of ram and the CLR does not need to run the  Garbage Collector. I was concerned because as more and more instances of the application are run by multiple users concurrently if the application will scale properly and not run out of memory so that swapping has to take place

Comment: You should be glad there is no collection happening when it's not needed -- that would just impact your program when it's not necessary. If you notice increased GC pressure with a higher load (which would be a reasonable expectation) then you can just turn on Server GC and see what impact it has. This should also be relatively trivial to test on your own without having to rely on your prod application.